# How to center text on top of a picture

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why my text is not centering in the middle of the page. I used margin-left and right set to auto. I am new to front end dev so I am currently having a bit of trouble. On my page, it is currently located on the left

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7rq7t0k/1/

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="background_image">
  </div>
  <div class="welcome-text-container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="welcome-text1">Welcome!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.background_image {
    background-image: image-url("header-bg.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 66.64%; 
    position: absolute;
    /* (img-height / img-width * width) */
    /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}

.welcome-text-container {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    /*display: block;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.row {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: You have to define width to: `.welcome-text-container { width: 100%; }`.

Comment: @emmanuel post an answer an I shall accepted it! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to **center** an element in screen you have to make sure that **container** width is set to `100%`.

```
.welcome-text-container { width: 100%; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7rq7t0k/3/

Answer (score 2):

It's cause by the "position" property. Look at this jsfiddle :

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/o7rq7t0k/2/`
```

Comment: You actually fixed another issue I had! THanks!